# How do I remove other substrings in a string in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

here are 5 rows of my column Genres in my table data

```
Classics, Fiction, Historical Fiction, School, Literature, Young Adult, Historical

Fantasy, Fiction, Young Adult, Magic, Childrens, Middle Grade, Classics

Classics, Fiction, Romance, Historical Fiction, Literature, Historical, Audiobook

Classics, Nonfiction, History, Biography, Memoir, Historical, Holocaust

Classics, Fiction, Dystopia, Fantasy, Politics, School, Literature
```

What syntax should i use to make sure that all rows only have either values:

Classics, Fiction, Literature, Young Adult, Fantasy

i am currently lost and all suggested solutions from the internet have resulted to nothing

Comment: You shouldn't save such data in a comma separated list, for exactly that reason. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return on your MySQL instance?

Comment: `SELECT VERSION();` return 8.0.36

Comment: Subj: *How do I **remove** other substrings in a string in mySQL?*. Text: *What syntax should i use to **make sure** that all rows only have either values*. Please decide what do you need in REALLY.

Comment: @Akina I think they're the same thing: Removing strings outside that list ensures that the rows only contain those strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, REPLACE(genres, ', ', ',') AS genres
  FROM data
)
UPDATE data JOIN cte USING (id)
SET data.genres = CONCAT_WS(',',
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('Classics', cte.genres), 'Classics', NULL),
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('Fiction', cte.genres), 'Fiction', NULL),
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('Literature', cte.genres), 'Literature', NULL),
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('Young Adult', cte.genres), 'Young Adult', NULL),
    IF(FIND_IN_SET('Fantasy', cte.genres), 'Fantasy', NULL));
```

Demo using MySQL 8.0: https://dbfiddle.uk/XpPxmhX1

The better solution is to store each genre in a separate row of a second table. This is a standard way to store many-to-many relationships.

---

Re your comment:

> is there a solution that takes into account the ordering?

If the ordering is significant, then I suppose the potential duplicates are also significant.

There could be a solution, but the more important point is that there shouldn't have to be.

Store the data in a normalized fashion, and it will be a lot easier. You won't have to solve hard problems like manipulating comma-separated lists.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE genres (
  genre VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY)
);

INSERT INTO genres VALUES ('Classics'), ('Fiction'), ('Literature'), ('Young Adult'), ('Fantasy');

CREATE TABLE data_genres (
  data_id INT NOT NULL,
  ordinal INT NOT NULL,
  genre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (data_id, ordinal)
  FOREIGN KEY (genre) REFERENCES genres(genre) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO data_genres VALUES
(1, 1, 'Classics'),
(1, 2, 'Fiction'),
(1, 3, 'Literature'),
(1, 4, 'Young Adult');
```

This stores one genre value per row, and only the values currently enumerated by the `genres` table. You can store them in any order you want in the `data_genre` table. It also permits duplicates if that's desired.

If you want to change the list of genres, then add or remove a row to the `genres` table.

Comment: Source data does not contain duplicated values, but OP does not tell that this is not possible. Also OP have not told that the ordering may be any. Nevertheless I hope that this solution is safe for OP...

Comment: Where is the comment about ordering that you're referring to? It's apparently been deleted, so maybe it's not important.

Answer (score 0):

A normalized table could look like:

```
CREATE TABLE NewGenres
WITH RECURSIVE nrs as (
  SELECT 1 as a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a+1 FROM nrs WHERE a<20)
,Genre as (
  SELECT R, a, trim(substring_index(substring_index(Genres,',',a),',',-1)) as Genre
  FROM nrs
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT row_number() over (order by Genres) R, Genres FROM mytable)  g
  WHERE a <= LENGTH(Genres)-LENGTH(REPLACE(Genres,',',''))+1
)
SELECT * 
FROM Genre
ORDER BY R,a;

SELECT * FROM NewGenres;
```

and used like this:

```
SELECT 
    R, 
    sum(CASE WHEN Genre in ('Classics', 'Fiction', 'Literature', 'Young Adult', 'Fantasy') then 1 else 0 end) as NrofGenresInList,
    count(*) NumberOfGenres,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Genre ORDER BY Genre)  as ListOfGenres
FROM NewGenres
GROUP BY R
;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/MB4WmcMu)

Comment: does this work on tables with thousands of rows? i tried using this on my database and it returned some rows with empty Genres.

Comment: @h1y2eons: Sorry, not enough info, but it should work on _thousands of rows_.